# DISTINCT on one column and return TOP rows

Tags: sql-server, distinct, top

How do you query for three unique customers with the largest `Purchase_Cost`?

I want to apply the `DISTINCT` only on `Customer_Name`, but the query below applies the distinct on all three columns. How should I modify the query to obtain the desired output?

```
SELECT DISTINCT TOP 3 customer_name, order_no, Purchase_Cost  
FROM PurchaseTable 
ORDER BY Purchase_Cost
```

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Replace your dbname and schemaName in the following query.

```
;WITH CTE AS 
(
SELECT  
       [Order_No]
      ,[Customer_Name]
      ,[Purchase_Cost]
     , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY [customer Name] ORDER BY [Purchase Cost] DESC) AS "RowNumber"
  FROM [dbname].[schemaName].[PurchaseTable]
  )

  SELECT TOP(3)
       [Order_No]
      ,[Customer_Name]
      ,[Purchase_Cost]
  FROM CTE WHERE RowNumber=1
  ORDER BY [Purchase_Cost] DESC
```

I am sure there are other ways of doing the same. I suggest you read [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-over-clause-transact-sql).

Answer (score 1):

please try:

```
SELECT DISTINCT TOP 3  order_no, customer_name,  Purchase_Cost
FROM
(   SELECT order_no, customer_name, Purchase_Cost, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY customer_name ORDER BY Purchase_Cost DESC) Orders
    FROM PurchaseTable
) A
WHERE A.Orders = 1
ORDER BY Purchase_Cost DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this could be more efficient that the other solutions, provided you have an index on: (Customer_Name, Purchase_Cost DESC) INCLUDE (Order_No)

```
;
WITH PurchaseTable AS
(
    SELECT * 
      FROM (VALUES ((501),('Carson'),(3400)),
                   ((502),('Thomas'),(625)),
                   ((503),('Daisy'),(4856)),
                   ((504),('Mary'),(2397)),
                   ((505),('Carson'),(5000))
           ) AS T(Order_No,Customer_Name,Purchase_Cost)
),
DistinctCustomers AS
(
    SELECT DISTINCT
           Customer_Name
      FROM PurchaseTable
)
SELECT TOP(3) 
       MaxCustomerOrder.Order_No,
       dc.Customer_Name,
       MaxCustomerOrder.Purchase_Cost
  FROM DistinctCustomers dc
 CROSS APPLY (SELECT TOP(1) * 
                FROM PurchaseTable pt 
               WHERE pt.Customer_Name = dc.Customer_Name 
               ORDER BY pt.Purchase_Cost DESC
             )    AS MaxCustomerOrder
 ORDER BY MaxCustomerOrder.Purchase_Cost DESC
;
```

Or without the inline table definition:

```
;
WITH DistinctCustomers AS
(
    SELECT DISTINCT
           Customer_Name
      FROM PurchaseTable
)
SELECT TOP(3) 
       MaxCustomerOrder.Order_No,
       dc.Customer_Name,
       MaxCustomerOrder.Purchase_Cost
  FROM DistinctCustomers dc
 CROSS APPLY (SELECT TOP(1) * 
                FROM PurchaseTable pt 
               WHERE pt.Customer_Name = dc.Customer_Name 
               ORDER BY pt.Purchase_Cost DESC
             )    AS MaxCustomerOrder
 ORDER BY MaxCustomerOrder.Purchase_Cost DESC
;
```

Comment: The first query does not look valid.

Comment: I tried to fix it. Not sure what the difference is between query 1 and 2.

Comment: Query 2 just has the inline table data removed. You don't need it if you actually have the table with the data in it. If you don't have the actual table, like me, you would need it to test that it runs.